# Xiaomi Mi Band 2 cannot be paired with App Mi Fit in Android 8.1.0

Tags: bluetooth, lg, 8.1-oreo, mi-band-2

I wanted to pair the [LG Q6](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_q6-8756.php) with the Mi Band 2.

I installed [Mi Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaomi.hm.health&hl=cs&gl=US), created a google account and wanted to pair with the device. However, after a while, an error is displayed stating that it couldn't be paired and if I want to reset the device.

If I select yes, the 4-digit number will be displayed on Mi Band 2. A window with a box where I should enter the number will appear on my mobile phone. However, this window is partially covered by another error message that it cannot be reset and whether to cancel or resend. In any case, this window cannot be hidden, so it was not possible to write the number.

So I uninstalled and installed the application, but the only thing that has changed is that the reset fails and the number doesn't appear on the device at all.

Please help

Thank you

PS. Android itself can be paired with the device.

**UPDATE**

I searched for a solution and found a link to [Fix-it for Mi Band 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mc.fixitformiband2&hl=cs). Although it has a low rating, I still tried. I followed the instructions and everything seemed fine, but it didn't help.

I would be grateful for a solution, but I personally gave it up.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem or did not? If you solved, would you share with me the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Yagiz I'm very sorry for the delayed answer. I wrote everything in answer to the question - it was enough to use another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, the solution was incredibly easy. At the time I was trying to pair it, it never occurred to me to try anything other than the official app. But since then, I've found that the official app may not always be the best. And here it was the same - it was enough to use another application - [Mi Band App for HRX, 2 and Mi Band 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.miband.mibandapp&hl=en_US&gl=US).

I haven't tested it yet, but the pairing itself worked, so hopefully there won't be another problem.